# Default rout setting with argument in CakePHP

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp-2.0

I am facing one problem in context to default routing setting in CakePHP. When I hit url to www.mydomain.com automatically it goes to www.mydomain.com/distributor/index. That working fine but when I am hitting url like www.mydomain.com/search, its not redirecting to www.mydomain.com/distributor/index instead its going to admin login page. I am using Authenticate component. So i have given allow permission to this action. My requirement is when I will hit url www.mydomain.com/search it should redirect to www.mydomain.com/distributor/index/search.

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'distributor', 'action' => 'index'));
```

I do appreciate for advance help

Answer (score 0):

Try This..

```
Router::connect('/search', array('controller' => 'distributor', 'action' => 'index'));
```